# How to reference Parent values when using GetChildElement to create new records via Apex

Tags: apex, xml

I have an Apex Class that is calling out from Salesforce to our Accounting system to pull back revenue data into Salesforce.  It does so by querying for a Contract record in the accounting system, then using that ID to query for any records in the ContractRevenueSchedule object.  If any records are found in the accounting systems ContractRevenueSchedule object, it then will loop through those records to get the subsequent ContractRevenueScheduleEntry records, which are then used to populate the values on our Revenue record in Salesforce.

Where i'm running into an issue is that I need to reference a value from the ContractRevenueSchedule record the ContractRevenueScheduleEntry record came from in creating the Salesforce Revenue record, but I can't figure out how to reference the parent value.

Below is a snippet of the code... When I save, I get a "Variable does not exist: LINENO" error, even though that is the correct field name from the ContractRevenueSchedule object.

I'm brand new to Apex and am trying to update an existing class to work on a new object... Any ideas?

```
   public void GetRevenueActivations(string name)
{
    
    string field = 'NAME';
    AddField('CONTRACTID');
    AddField('NAME');
    
    query = field + ' = \'' + name + '\'';
    
    obj = 'CONTRACT';
    
    
    //  readRequest.setDocParId('Revenue Activation');
    
    OnlineResponse resp = ExecuteReadByQuery(field);
    System.debug(resp);
    Reset();
    GetRevenueSchedules(resp);
}

private OnlineResponse ExecuteReadByQuery(string field)
{
    QueryString requestQuery = new QueryString(query);
    
    ReadByQuery readRequest = new ReadByQuery();
    readRequest.setObjectName(obj);
    readRequest.setFields(fields);
    readRequest.setQuery(requestQuery);
    readRequest.setPageSize(pageSize);
    
    return client.execute(readRequest, new RequestConfig());
}

private void GetRevenueScheduleById(string revRecId)
{
    
    
    AddField('RECORDNO');
    
    
    obj = 'CONTRACTREVENUESCHEDULE';
    integer counter = 0;
 
    query = 'CONTRACTID' + ' = \'' + revRecId + '\'';
    OnlineResponse revSchedule = ExecuteReadByQuery('');
    
    System.debug('revSchedule ' + revSchedule);
    Reset();
    GetRevenueScheduleEntries(revSchedule);
    Reset();
}

private void GetRevenueSchedules(OnlineResponse resp)
{
    
    
    AddField('RECORDNO');
    AddField('LINENO');
    
    
    obj = 'CONTRACTREVENUESCHEDULE';
    boolean isContractIdSet = false;
    integer counter = 0;
    query = 'CONTRACTID' + ' = \'';
    for (Result nodes : resp.results)
    {
        
        string CONTRACTID = '';
        
        for (dom.XmlNode res : nodes.getData())
        {
            if (res.getName() == 'CONTRACT')
            {
                for (dom.XmlNode r : res.getChildElements())
                {
                    if (r.getName() == 'CONTRACTID')
                    {
                        CONTRACTID = r.getText();
                        isContractIdSet = true;
                        obj = 'CONTRACTREVENUESCHEDULE';
                        
                        if(counter == 0)
                        {
                            query = 'CONTRACTID' + ' = \'' + CONTRACTID + '\'';
                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            query =  query +' OR ' +'CONTRACTID' + ' = \''  + CONTRACTID+ '\'';
                        }
                        
                        counter++;

                        {
                            
                            System.debug('#############################');
                            System.debug('#GetRevenueScheduleEntries###');
                            System.debug(CONTRACTID);
                            
                            System.debug('#############################');
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    OnlineResponse revSchedule = ExecuteReadByQuery('');
    
    System.debug('revSchedule ' + revSchedule);
    Reset();
    GetRevenueScheduleEntries(revSchedule);
    Reset();
}

public void GetRevenueScheduleEntries(OnlineResponse resp)
{
    AddField('*');
    
    
    obj = 'CONTRACTREVENUESCHEDULEENTRY';
    boolean isContractIdSet = false;
    
    Result nodes = resp.results[0];
    integer counter = 0;
    string recordNo = '';
    query = 'SCHEDULEKEY' + ' = \'';
    boolean executeQuery = false;
    if (nodes.getData() == null)
        return;
    for (dom.XmlNode res : nodes.getData())
    {
        System.debug('nodes ');
        
        if (res.getName() == 'CONTRACTREVENUESCHEDULE')
        {
            for (dom.XmlNode r : res.getChildElements())
            {
                if (r.getName() == 'RECORDNO')
                {
                    executeQuery = true;
                    recordNo = r.getText();
                    isContractIdSet = true;
                    
                    if(counter == 0)
                    {
                        query = 'SCHEDULEKEY' + ' = \'' + recordNo + '\'';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        query = query + ' OR '+'SCHEDULEKEY' + ' = \'' + recordNo + '\'';
                        
                    }
                    counter++;
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    System.debug('#############################');
    System.debug('#############################');
    
    System.debug('#############################');
    if(executeQuery)
    {
        OnlineResponse revSchedule = ExecuteReadByQuery('');
        CreateRevRecSched(revSchedule, RECORDNO);
        System.debug('revSchedule ' + revSchedule);
    }
    
}

private void CreateRevRecSched(OnlineResponse resp, String RECORDNO)
{
    System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
    System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
    
    System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
    System.debug(resp.results[0].getData());
    for (Dom.XMLNode revRec : resp.results[0].getData())
    {
        
        Intacct_Revenue_Recognition_Schedule__c sched = null;
        System.debug('Rec sched entry');
        System.debug(revRec);
        ///string dept = revRec.getChildElement('DEPT', null).getText();
        ///string agency = revRec.getChildElement('GLDIMAGENCY', null).getText();
        
        ///string agencycode = '';
        
        ///string departmentcode = '';
        
        ///if (String.isNotBlank(dept))
        ///{
        ///    if (this.DepartmentMap.containsKey(dept))
       ///         departmentcode = this.DepartmentMap.get(dept);
        ///}
        
        ///if (String.isNotBlank(agency))
        ///{
        ///    if (this.AgencyMap.containsKey(agency))
        ///        agencycode = this.AgencyMap.get(agency);
       /// } //revRecMap
        string recordNumber = revRec.getChildElement('RECORDNO', null).getText();
        recNumsFromIntaact.add(recordNumber);
        decimal amount = 0.0;
        amount = Decimal.valueOf(revRec.getChildElement('AMOUNT', null).getText());



        
        System.debug('Amount ' + amount);
        string dt = revRec.getChildElement('POSTINGDATE', null).getText().replace('/', '-');
        
        //string curr = revRec.getChildElement('CURRENCY', null).getText();
        //string custom = revRec.getChildElement('CUSTOMERID', null).getText() + '--' + revRec.getChildElement('CUSTOMERNAME', null).getText();
        //string deptc = revRec.getChildElement('DEPT', null).getText() + '--' + departmentcode;
        //string employee = revRec.getChildElement('EMPLOYEENAME', null).getText();
        //string accountNo = revRec.getChildElement('ACCOUNTNO', null).getText() + '--' + revRec.getChildElement('ACCOUNTTITLE', null).getText();
        //string item = revRec.getChildElement('ITEMID', null).getText() + '--' + revRec.getChildElement('ITEMNAME', null).getText();
        //string produc = revRec.getChildElement('CLASSID', null).getText() + '--' + revRec.getChildElement('CLASSNAME', null).getText();
        decimal recNum = Decimal.valueOf(revRec.getChildElement('RECORDNO', null).getText());
        //string journal = revRec.getChildElement('GLJOURNAL', null).getText();
        
        boolean isCreate = false;
        
        System.debug('recordNumber  '+ recordNumber);
        System.debug(revRecMap);
        if (!revRecMap.containsKey(recordNumber))
        {
            sched = new Intacct_Revenue_Recognition_Schedule__c();
            isCreate = true;
            
        }
        else {
            sched = revRecMap.get(recordNumber);
        }
        
        
        sched.Amount__c = amount;
        sched.Name = oppId;
        ///sched.Agency__c = agencycode;
        ///sched.Currency__c = curr;
        ///sched.Customer__c = custom;
        ///sched.Department__c = deptc;
        ///sched.Employee__c = employee;
        ///sched.Account_Number__c = accountNo;
        ///sched.Item__c = item;
        ///sched.Product__c = produc;
        sched.Quantity__c = 1;
        sched.RECORDNO__c = recNum;
        ///sched.Journal__c = journal;
        
        sched.Posting_Date__c = setStringToDateFormat(dt);
        sched.Source_Transaction__c = RECORDNO;
        ///sched.Intacct_Contract_ID__c = CONTRACTID;
        ///sched.Intacct_Contract_Detail_Key__c = CONTRACTDETAILKEY;
        ///sched.Intacct_Contract_Key__c = CONTRACTKEY;
        ///sched.Intacct_Contract_line_GL_posting_date__c = CNDETAILGLPOSTINGDATE;
        sched.Intacct_Contract_line_no__c = LINENO;
        ///sched.Intacct_End_date__c = ENDDATE;
        ///sched.Intacct_Record_URL__c = RECORD_URL;
        ///sched.Intacct_Schedule_status__c = STATE;
        ///sched.Intacct_Schedule_type__c = TYPE;
        ///sched.Intacct_Start_date__c = STARTDATE;
        
        if (isCreate)
        {
            if (code == 0)
            {
                sched.Sales_Order_ID__c = oppId;
            }
            else {
                sched.Intacct_Contract__c = oppId;
                sched.Sales_Order_ID__c = defaultOrder.Id;
            }
            
            System.debug('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^');
            System.debug('Adding');
            System.debug(revSchedsToCreate);
            revSchedsToCreate.add(sched);
            
        }
        else {
            revSchedsToUpdate.add(sched);
        }
        
        System.debug('IsUpdate : ' + isCreate);
        System.debug('rev rec ' + sched);
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because you don't actually have any variable called 'LINENO', rather than there being an issue with the field name. If you've gotten this out of your response you'll need to actually store this as a variable for you to use later on, or create a Map of the element name and value pairs in your response for you to then retrieve the value based on the element name.